# Windows 11: Mistake during deleting disk partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-11

I was trying to install Linux on a boot partition, I have mistakenly erased this 128MB Windows 11 partition.

[image: Disk Management screenshot]

Windows seems to work fine, but anyway, what should I do? What did I erase? How can I restore it?

Comment: Did you install Windows 11 by yourself? It doesn't seem to match the default partition layout (Recovery Partition (contains WinRE) + EFI boot partition + MSR (not shown in Disk Managment, 16 MB) + Windows Partition (main user partition)) (other orders possible). It may have been an OEM partition.

Comment: Is the computer booting normally?

Comment: What was the original partition? How can we provide an assement of any potential issues without having adequate information?

Comment: @ComputerUser121212
I do not but I am using a secon hand pc. Should I re-install Windows 11 by myself?

Comment: @harrymc How can I understand that?

Comment: @Ramhound The original partition did not have partition 4 and 5

Comment: If the computer is booting normally, I wouldn't worry too much about whatever was that partition.

Comment: @Lisa - Perhaps you should [edit] your question to clarify what it was. It's still not clear what the 128 MB partition was. Since it exists before the system partition it clear was something. How exactly was the partition deleted?

Comment: Welcome Lisa!  When you post in one SE site, and then realize that your question is instead on-topic on a different SE site, please either delete your original question or wait for the moderators of the original site to migrate your question to the appropriate SE site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

128 MB cannot be the Windows partition. A few mini-Linux distros might fit in that, but not Windows.

Likely it was the [Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR)](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000148607/what-is-the-128mb-partition-that-is-created-during-the-installation-of-windows): "This partition is required for GUID and must reside before the primary (Windows) partition. Some users may wish to delete this partition, however it is required for GPT partition drives."

If you do not have a partition named MSR, [it can be recreated](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/gpt-reserved-partition-128mb.html). Theoretically, it contains GUID and boot files... however, on this PC on which I'm writing, MSR is empty and other partitions have boot info. However, if it is working now, I'd set aside those instructions for later use, **if** an issue occurs.

Comment: It's so odd and confusing that MS uses `GUID` by itself in that sentence, given that MS has historically defined a GUID as a short 128-bit semi-unique string.  The previous sentence in their document clarifies a little, but it's still less than ideal.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket it is because the full name of the GPT partitioning scheme is [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and partition types and unique IDs are defined by GUIDs instead of a hex value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs

Answer (score 2):

When installed from scratch by regular setup media, Windows will create this 128MB partition just before its OS partition on a GPT partitioned disk.

This partition is not formated.
This partition is of type "Reserved"  (or "Microsoft reserved" or "MSR")
The Partition-Type UUID is `e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae`

1. Recreate this partition by reserving the whole unpartitioned space,
2. assign the correct type and leave it alone.
3. Do not try to assign a volume or a filesystem and
4. do not try to format it.

To get an idea about the purpose of this area, see [here at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition).

At the times of MBR I've found counters for license usage, some secret keys and more hidden in the raw space beyond partitions and filesystems.
Such unmanaged areas are not allowed on disks with GPT.

As you never know what some programs try to hide and how they react if they cannot do it, you should maintain this "raw, wild space" in the fence of a "reserved" partition. — It's a difference to have a windows installation that starts without this space and a living installation that looses its hidden data area.